Eclipse TFS plugin not respecting the ignore files\folders
Not sure why the ingnore is not being respected in eclipse TFS  plugin. I have marked the following files to be ignored as in the following screenshot:

When I right click on the project -> Teams -> Check in Pending Changes I get files from under the target folder as ready to check in !

I even went to the preferences -> Version Control -> Ignore Resoures and added those files specifically there:

I went to to TFS Pending Changes and click to exclude and there should not be any files that needs to be checked in :

EDIT LATER:
After more research I found that the issue and the resolution are explained well here:
Team Explorer Everywhere - Remove Ignored files from Pending Changes
Closing this ticket.

The [Ignore] label is added by the TFS plugin. The general exclude pattern from any version control system would for the Maven target folder would be */target/*, not target. By the way, the dark theme plugin you have installed patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other dark themes that are more ergonomic and don't do this.

I tried your suggesion of adding the */target/* to  preferences -> Version Control -> Ignore Resoures but it did not help I still get the files when I try to do check in pending changes! Are you talking about the Planet Themes plugin??

The TFS plugin might ignore what have been set in Eclipse in the preferences Version Control > Ignore Resoures. I'm talking about this plugin and other plugins from the same company.

yeah I guess that is the plug in I use. Which one do you recommend? Is there a way to overcome the ingore issue so the plugin can ingnore what Im trying to ignore
